# Scrapy image download pipeline - image expiry

Tags: scrapy

A simple question. Scrap allows for an image expiry to prevent downloading the same images multiple times. How does scrapy know which images it has already downloaded, if these images were downloaded during a previous run?

Comment: are you talking about image **content**? because then it is much harder, or just image urls, because then it could be any kind of request or url.

Comment: also scrapy doesn't make duplicate requests, you need to specify the meta parameter `dont_filter` to bypass that rule.